# Trim a string in R

Tags: regex, string, r, gsub

I am trying to isolate a portion of a string in R. The strings have the form  `ABC_constantStuff_ABC_randomStuff` and `ABC` is what I am trying to extract. `ABC` is unknown and  can be 1-3 characters long. I've been trying `grep` and `gsub` but am unsure how to specify my regular expression using

```
str <- 'GDP\" title=\"GDP - News\"></a>"'
symbol <- gsub(pattern,'',str)
```

Here `GDP` is unknown and can be 1-3 characters long, `\" title=\"` is constant in every string and I would like to remove `\" title=\"GDP - News\"></a>"`

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: If you're parsing HTML, make sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/16632

Comment: Thanks for the link. xml package is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple one is

```
R> gsub("^([A-Z]*)_.*", "\\1", "ABC_constantStuff_ABC_randomStuff")
[1] "ABC"
R>
```

which gets all letters up to the first `_`.

Another one assumming `_` is your separator is

```
R> strsplit( "ABC_constantStuff_ABC_randomStuff", "_")[[1]][c(1,3)]
[1] "ABC" "ABC"
R>
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this help?

```
> sub("\".*$", "", str)
```